# Detect dates between strings and times using momentjs

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, datetime, internationalization, momentjs

I have a string like this

```
Occurs every 1 weeks on Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday and Saturday effective 2015-07-23T00:00:00 from T16:00:00 to T17:00:00
```

You can see I got words, times and dates. I need to apply formats to dates and times, and internationalization to strings.

The code works like this

```
var result = '';
// get values as an array
var arrValue = value.split(' '), resultArr = [];
// iterate in each element
for (var i = 0; i < arrValue.length; i++) {
    // validate is a date
    if (moment(arrValue[i], moment.ISO_8601).isValid() && (arrValue[i].indexOf('T') != -1)) {
        // push into array
        resultArr.push(moment(arrValue[i]).format('L'));
        // validate is a time
    } else if (moment('0001-01-01' + arrValue[i], moment.ISO_8601).isValid() && (arrValue[i].indexOf('T') != -1)) {
        // push as a result the date
        resultArr.push(moment('0001-01-01' + arrValue[i]).format('LT'));
    } else {
        // push the string in the collection
        resultArr.push(sgI18NService.translate(['portfolio', 'activity-recurrence-field-' + arrValue[i]], arrValue[i]));
    }
}
```

which it works fine (then I join the strings). The problem is that in IE is not working properly to recognize some strings, and it confuses them as a Date, for example, after I split the strings I got every day as a string and when I evaluate

```
moment('0001-01-01Thursday,', moment.ISO_8601).isValid()
```

I get false in Chrome (which is fine, since Thursday is a string, not a date) BUT in IE I get true. I checked and it looks like that is transforming that invalid date to minimum date

```
Tue Jan 01 1901 00:00:00 GMT-0500
```

That example was when evaluating the second if. I have this issue of getting valid dates with Thursday and with Tuesday.
What I'm doing wrong ? How can I difference strings from dates and from times in IE ?

edit: The strings are limited, I have different combination of string but they are not entered by the user.

Comment: perhaps you want a space in there? `...-01 Thursday`? `01Thursday` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I need it to recognize times, because for something like this `T17:00:00` I would  have  `0001-01-01T17:00:00` which is valid (that would recognize it as a Time) but  `0001-01-01 T17:00:00` is not (so I won't know if its a time or a string)

Comment: well, there's the problem. if you can't tell which is which, how can you expect the JS engine to be able to? it's got some pretty decent heuristics, but it ain't "smart"...

Comment: Well I would expect that '0001-01-01Thursday,' is a string because it is not a date, but IE is recognizing it as a date..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as my input strings were limited and I knew the case I would have, I matched the string to have numbers

```
/\d/.test()
```

worked for me